# log4net with SQL Server CE don't save data to table

Tags: sql-server-ce, log4net, log4net-configuration, .net-cf-3.5, windows-embedded-compact

**Edit 2**

What I have found out now is very strange. When I turn on unmanaged exception in Visual studio i get an format exception when trying

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.Uri(config));
```

I have added some parameters to my insert and added more values

```
      <commandText
              value="INSERT INTO [Log] 
              ([Message], [Name]) 
              VALUES 
              (@log_level, @message)" />

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="100" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
```

It seems like if I remove my dbType tags in the parameter sections it goes a bit longer in my code. However, then I get a format exception when trying to log. If I remove one of the parameters (so I only insert with one value) it logs. I have tried inserting only one value at time (message or log_level) and it works fine but together it breaks.

If I only insert dummy-data directly in my config-sql it works with both values. SO it seems to be something very strange going on with log4Net.

Any idvise is appreciated!

**end edit 2**

**Edit**

After some trial and error and help I have changed the buffersize from 100 to 0. 
it seems to be some problem with righting to the SDF-file.

After restarting my device on my virtual machine I get a log error when my path to the sed-file is wrong. However when I get that correct a I get an error when I'm trying to log to the file stating "The remote connection to the device has been lost. PLease verify the device connection and restart debugging"

**End edit**

I'm trying to log some stuff to a SQL Server CE database on my WindowsCE device. When I log to a file everything goes as it should but when using an `AdoNetAppender` it won't work.

My log4net.config looks like this:

```
<appender name="SQLCEAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="0"/>
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection, System.Data.SqlServerCe" />
  <commandText
    value="INSERT INTO [Loging2] 
    ([Val]) 
    VALUES 
    ('1')" />
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
    <levelMin value="INFO" />
    <levelMax value="INFO" />
  </filter>
</appender>

<!-- Define some output appenders -->
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="Log.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <header type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
      <conversionPattern value="[Header %property{windowsversion}]%newline" />
    </header>
    <footer value="[Footer]&#13;&#10;" />
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
    <levelMin value="INFO" />
    <levelMax value="INFO" />
  </filter>
</appender>
<root>
    <!--<level value="All" />-->
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="SQLCEAppender" />
</root>
```

I have tried to have only the file appender and/or the sqldatabase appender active but no result. I have also striped my SQL query into a dummy insert only to rule out key/null values and so on.

And in my `app.xaml.cs` (Silverlight application), I have this code only to make the configuration and to set the correct path to the `.sdf` file.

```
var codeBase = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(codeBase);
var path = Path.Combine(directory, "log4Net.config");

log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new Uri(path));

var repo = LogManager.GetRepository();
var appender = repo.GetAppenders()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("SQLCEAppender")) as AdoNetAppender;

appender.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + Path.Combine(directory, "Log.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;");
appender.ActivateOptions();

ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (App));
log.Info("Starting application");
log.Debug("Printing debug");
```

I get a fine debug log (I have some more appenders in my config), and in my file. When I look at the appender object it says that it is open to database and if I modify the path to the `.sdf` file to be something wrong, the appender isn't saying that the connection is fine.

What am I missing? I have also set the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` to be copied and I can see the dll on the device.

Answer (score 2):

You have the bufferSize set to 100. The amount of characters you log, don't exceed the bufferSize. Try to set it to 0 and test whether it works.

Comment: That seems to make some progress :)
However when I log no I get a error (from VS) saying "The remote connection to the device has been lost. Please verify the device connection and restart debugging."

My device is still connected.

Comment: Seems like there is something wrong with your connection string. Try to input it hardcoded (e.g. "C:/Log.sdf"). If that works, then there is something wrong with the calculation of your connection string.

Comment: So now it don't break. I removed "Data Source". But still no data in my table :(